# Use a sql native query when you are using a parameter to connect to an oracle db

Tags: powerbi

When I tried to connect to my oracle db by using a parameter in power bi it would return with an error after inputting a parameter

THe error

```
We encountered an error while trying to connect Details: " EvaluateNativeQueryUnpermitted failure: the query SELECT * FROM table isn't approved for execution
```

I try to use a parameter when connecting in inputting a sql command,

Comment: Parameters are no problem, you just have to approve the query again after every update.

Comment: sorry I think my question isn't very clear, I am wanting to use a parameter instead of directly inputing my connection string, I then click on advanced options and want to input a native query but when I input one then a error returns but it I keep the native query section empty then my database returns a list of tables. however i prefer using sql native queries

Comment: actually i do see it says isn't approved for execution but how would I approve the sql query

Comment: I managed to get the native query to work with the parameter I unticked in options -> security -> require user approval for new native queries. But this may not be good for security reasons